# Show a new row when something is written in the row above it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a predefined sheet where new employee names are generated, including their personal Info. I am looking for a script or fce, which can do this:

hide all empty rows;
once a value in cell (for example, A5) is entered -> new row is shown;
when a value is entered in the same cell on the new shown row (e.g., A6) -> another is shown, etc.;
And it all should be performed on a sheet called "JobWorkers"

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide all the blank rows first by selecting the first row, then pressing the ctrl shift down arrow, then right click and select hide rows.  Then you go to the script editor and have this onEdit function, that will see the last row, and unhide the next row.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.showRows(lastRow+1);
}
```